# TestDecor_1.TestDeco is not a constructor

Tags: typescript

below is mycode:

1) DecorTest.ts:

```
export const symbolPrefix = Symbol('prefix');
export const controller = (path) =>  (target) => 
target.prototype[symbolPrefix] = path;
```

2）TestDecor.ts

```
import {controller} from './DecorTest';

@controller('aaa')
export class TestDeco {
  private name: string;
  constructor(AName: string) {
    this.name = AName;
  }
}
```

3) app.ts

```
import {TestDeco } from './router/TestDecor';
const testdec = new TestDeco('bb');

var keys = [];
for(var i in testdec) {
  if(testdec.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    keys.push(i)
  }
}
```

4) then ,i compile it ,compiler shows error :TestDecor_1.TestDeco is not a constructor in app.js

5)below is app.js compiled

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');
const mainrouter_1 = require("./router/mainrouter");
const TestDecor_1 = require("./router/TestDecor");
const testdec = new TestDecor_1.TestDeco('bb');  //error locate this line
var keys = [];
for (var i in testdec) {
  if (testdec.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    keys.push(i);
  }
}
console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If we look at the documentation for decorators:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators)

> If the class decorator returns a value, it will replace the class declaration with the provided constructor function.

Now let's look at the decorator:

```
export const controller = (path) => (target) => target.prototype[symbolPrefix] = path;
```

When writing an arrow function, leaving off the braces creates an implicit return, and assignment expressions return the value that's being assigned, so the end result of the decorator is returning whatever `path` is.

Here's what happens in usage:

```
// this...
@controller('aaa')
export class TestDeco {
  private name: string;
  constructor(AName: string) {
    this.name = AName;
  }
}

// roughly becomes this
export const TestDeco = 'aaa'
```

Then, `new TestDeco()` is problematic, because using `new` with a string doesn't make sense, and JS gets angry.

So the solution is to put a set of braces around the code for your decorator, to make sure it changes the prototype without actually returning anything.

```
export const controller = (path) => (target) => {
  target.prototype[symbolPrefix] = path;
}
```

Comment: dude,it works,good answer,made me understand what it is going on ,thank u very much